# Is the DOM readily rebuilt when jQuerys .load('url') is "complete"?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to build a website using ajax.

I want to replace a part of the page with new html/php and then run a javascript that needs access to the *updated* DOM.

I figured that using jQuerys [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) -function and calling the script from the "complete"-callback (see link) will fit my needs best. My question is: Can I assume the DOM to be ready and rebuilt once the "complete" - callback is executed?

Comment: That seems to be what's explicitly stated in the API: *If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.*

Comment: Ok, I wasn't so sure if that meant that the dom is there, but you are right, it wouldn't make sense otherwise. As for the last sentence: Does that mean that the callback-function I assign will be called multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the new script will have full access to the new DOM.